How can radio LCR circuits help read FM signals?
I just read about the application of LCR circuits in radio tuning in my textbook. The book does not go into much detail so I had to search for most of the information online.
Here's what I understood -
Say we have five radio stations, emitting out radio waves at five different frequencies. The radio has a receiver that catches these waves and runs an AC source of an LCR circuit using the superposition of these five waves as its basis for the waveform of the voltage in the source. The voltage now has a similar-looking waveform as the superposition of the five waves. Each of the five voltages produces some hypothetical current and the actual current is the superposition of all five currents. Now, to hear some station we need to tune the capacitor in the LCR circuit so that the resonant frequency of the LCR circuit becomes equal to the frequency of the voltage corresponding to that station. This makes the current due to that channel shoot up. Now this current will overshadow the other four currents and will carry whatever information the wave of that station was carrying.
But I can only see how this could work in an AM radio wave. The amplitudes decide the RMS current during resonance and hence the current carries the information that the wave was carrying.
How can this be used in FM radio? If the frequency of the wave is itself not constant what will we match the resonant frequency to? Is an LCR circuit even used in this case?
PS - I intially asked this on physics stack exchange but then thought this would be a more appropriate space. I am not an electrical engineering student.

AM has a bandwidth just as FM has a bandwidth so, what's the difference?

@Andyaka Yeah, I do think that FM having a bandwidth is an answer to my question. What I understood is that all the frequency changes can be accomodated in that bandwidth and hence will be reflected in the output current in the circuit.

The LCR circuit isn't 'perfect' -- it does not reach to only one precise frequency -- it reacts to a band (therefore it has a bandwidth). In either AM or FM, the bandwidth of the LCR will be made appropriate for the signal to be received. They can be done by changing the R value.
Another way of saying this is that the LCR is a filter. It passes different frequencies with different amounts of gain (or attenuation). In a real radio, there are effectively multiple cascaded LCR filters.
Once the desired signal is (mostly) filtered by the LCR filters (this is called selectivity), it is demodulated (i.e. converted back to the audio that originally modulated it). In some cases this signal will also contain some portions of the unwanted signals (i.e. other channels) -- it can be further filtered (usually by R.C-type circuits, not LCR) to only pass the desired channel.
In modern radios, there aren't even R.C filers -- the signal is converted to digital by an analog-digital converter and the filtering is performed digitally (i.e. mathematically).

So does this mean that all frequency modulations from the station will be done staying within the bandwidth? Then frequency stighty away from peak resonance frequency produces slightly smaller currents whereas frequencies closer to the resonance frequency produce higher currents and this can be used to encode information?

Yes, all the (useful) FM info stays within the bandwidth (~ 200 kHz for broadcast FM). The LCR is not so precise that it usefully responds to only a portion of the BW.
Some types of FM demodulation DO use the shoulders of the LCR response to convert FM to AM signals and therefore demodulate the signal.
